# Prevent &nbsp; from auto coming in frontend

Tags: html, laravel, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap tabs in laravel. But on frontend lots of `&nbsp;` coming up even when there is nothing mentioned in html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="tab" role="tabpanel">
                <!-- Nav tabs -->
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#Section1" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#Section2" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#Section3" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Section 3</a></li>
                </ul>
                <!-- Tab panes -->
                <div class="tab-content tabs">
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="Section1">
                        <h3>Section 1</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nec urna aliquam, ornare eros vel, malesuada lorem. Nullam faucibus lorem at eros consectetur lobortis. Maecenas nec nibh congue, placerat sem id, rutrum velit. Phasellus porta enim at facilisis condimentum. Maecenas pharetra dolor vel elit tempor pellentesque sed sed eros. Aenean vitae mauris tincidunt, imperdiet orci semper, rhoncus ligula. Vivamus scelerisque.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="Section2">
                        <h3>Section 2</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nec urna aliquam, ornare eros vel, malesuada lorem. Nullam faucibus lorem at eros consectetur lobortis. Maecenas nec nibh congue, placerat sem id, rutrum velit. Phasellus porta enim at facilisis condimentum. Maecenas pharetra dolor vel elit tempor pellentesque sed sed eros. Aenean vitae mauris tincidunt, imperdiet orci semper, rhoncus ligula. Vivamus scelerisque.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="Section3">
                        <h3>Section 3</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nec urna aliquam, ornare eros vel, malesuada lorem. Nullam faucibus lorem at eros consectetur lobortis. Maecenas nec nibh congue, placerat sem id, rutrum velit. Phasellus porta enim at facilisis condimentum. Maecenas pharetra dolor vel elit tempor pellentesque sed sed eros. Aenean vitae mauris tincidunt, imperdiet orci semper, rhoncus ligula. Vivamus scelerisque.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is how it appears in output

[image]

How can I remove those unwanted

Comment: `document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/&nbsp;/g," ")` ;)
Your backend or file is full of `A0` characters

Comment: Which IDE do you use? Good IDEs offer an option to "show control characters". Some IDEs even offer an option to remove trailing spaces on save.

Comment: @shaedrich I am using vs code editor

Comment: @mplungjan So what should I do? Never faced such issue before.

Comment: View→Render Control Characters and View→Render Whitespace

Comment: In your VS editor, make sure it does not add spaces as non-breaking spaces, and the files you have, grep them for \uA0